# Expo.io Offline Testing on iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo.io v29.0.0 for a react-native app.  I want to test downloading a video, then viewing it offline.  It appears there is no way to develop on the device while offline, its a known limitation (https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/developer-workflow-for-offline-support).

So my question: is the only way to test offline functionality on the iOS device to "publish" my app to expo.io, then download it to the device using their client app or something?

Answer (score 2):

We asked the same question and ended up with the same answer. In order to do offline testing we are publishing to expo and then downloading it.

We're doing debugging by writing to the screen and publishing/downloading with every change.

Can't wait for them to support this feature.

Comment: any news on this, facing similar issue 2 years on

Comment: We're on SDK 40 now, but the component we were working on is completed so the short answer is I don't know. Sorry.